# Location of data directories under AEgir on Debian

Tags: backups, aegir

I've got an out-of-the-box AEgir installation (Apache2, MySQL) running on Debian on a VirtualBox machine. I'd like to move the site data directories off the virtual drive onto my host's drive and use VirtualBox's shared folders to access them.

Which directories do I need to move?

`/var/aegir/platforms` is already on the host.

`/var/lib/mysql` holds the sites, so I will move that.

`/var/aegir/clients` would also need to be moved.

Are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/aegir/config` and `/var/aegir/backups`

Or you could just move the entire /var/aegir/ tree